# Is it possible to sign transactions offline in Mist?

Tags: transactions, mist, signature, offline

is this planned to be implemented? Would be great to be able to sign transactions securely on an air-gapped machine.

I understand that IceBox has offline signing, but they don't support contracts/multisig and custom tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using MyEtherWallet (https://www.myetherwallet.com/) where the source code is available for downloading to an offline computer from  https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet .

A note from their "Advance / Offline Transaction" page - "This tab is brand-spanking-new. Please report any bugs / issues in the reddit thread & please test with SMALL AMOUNTS FOR NOW! Thank you!"

Nice work https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/300/tayvano .

Comment: Thank you! FYI, the only issues we've had with that tab in the ~30 days it's been around is people don't know how to use it. One sent numerous times to (bad?) contract that had an out of gas error when trying to pass the funds along and the funds were stuck and he couldn't get it out. We were blamed, of course. Other than that, no issues. The warning should be updated / removed.